# In React with react-router, how can I keep all of a person's in-view choices when navigating away from a complex view, then directly back?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, html5-history

### React app Scenario

I have 2 views, UserLister and UserViewer.  Both are at different urls.  UserLister is a complex table (third party using ag-Grid), with fields, and sort and filtering.  UserViewer is an exceedingly complex view with a ton of functionality that takes a while to load up. I want to make it really performant and user friendly to navigate **back** to UserLister after viewing an individual User.  I want it to display all the same sorts and the same information as the user has set up.

To put it another way:

- I want the changes that I (or any person) uses on listing page 1 to be available if someone navigates away and then directly back.

### Idiomatic way to accomplish this?

How can I accomplish this best in react? is there some function of react-router that would apply here? I would prefer not to have to manage the *?100s?* of different states that the UserLister has for sorting/filtering/selecting data manually.

Comment: it sounds to me like you need to use global state, like redux. when you navigate away the component is unmounted, an when you navigate back it is re-rendered , and remounted. local state does not persist. a global state would.

Comment: alternatively you could store the user's selections in localStorage or cookies or something...but this is not a scalable way to manage global state as your project grows.

Answer (score 0):

React-router is routing library which manages browser history. You need another tool to save and share state between components. The idea is to make both UserLister and UserViewer to store and access information from some kind of global storage. So each time user enters specific Route data persists.

There are plenty of ways how to do that. Most idiomatic way is to use [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook and then implement "vanilla" [Flux architecture](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) (aka unidirectional data flow) in your app.

If you don't want to write all boilerplate by yourself (no judgement here), you can look at [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), which will do most background work for you.

Redux still requires some good amount of boilerplating. If you don't like it and feel more like streams and observables guy, you can use [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/), which implements reactive programming patterns for state management.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I am aware that I could manage all the pieces of state myself.  However, there's a lot of state, and I'm using a third-party library that may make it quite difficult to watch over the state or props.  And of course, whatever the user has displayed is already -exactly- what I want to show.  So I'd really love to not having to manually manage the state.